# How to make a console inventory system dynamic

Tags: c++

I have an inventory system that stores "Item" types which is an abstract class. I have a derived class called "Skates". The program allows the user to add "Skates" into a vector of "Item" pointers. The user input the model and ID of the skates and I create a "Skates" object with those as the parameters. Then I use an "Item" pointer to point to that "Skates" object and add it into the vector. When the user wants to edit the "Skates" object I have to dynamic_cast it back to a "Skates" object and then edit it.

```
std::vector<Item*> ItemCollection;
Item * item = new Skates("model1", 1);
ItemCollection.push_back(item);
//To retrieve it
Skates * skatesToEdit = dynamic_cast<Skates*>(ItemCollection[0]);
```

The problem I am facing now is to account for a new derived class, "Skateboard" class for example. I don't want to create a new method to handle the editing of the "Skateboard" class like:

```
Skateboard * skateboardToEdit = dynamic_cast<Skateboard*>(ItemCollection[0]);
```

Since this would mean that everytime I make a new derived class I need to write this same style of code everytime. So I would like to know if there is a way to make the application dynamically know what derived class it is without me needing to specify it. So it needs to be able to determine the datatype and then prompt the user to edit whatever property it has (since the goal is for users to edit the object in the first place) in one dynamic method which I think should be impossible.

Comment: Do you need to know what the item is?  Could you not create a pure virtual function for Item, override it in Skates and Skateboard and just call the virtual function as a member function of ItemCollection[x]?  That way, you don't need to know what item is: the system will sort it out for you.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see how that would allow me to return the Item as the derived class for me to edit the properties specific to that derived class. I may be misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that maybe inheritance is not what you need here. Instead of having classes like Skates, Skateboard, consider having just class Item, which is collection of key values representing properties. This way you don't really care about class of the item and you can list and edit properties dynamically.

Comment: I know what u mean to just have the "Item" class but there are two reasons I need the inheritance: to account for different kinds of Items and because this is an assignment which marks for inheritance

Comment: @Stein121 you don't need inheritance for that really. You can just have a field type and store it there. Inheritance is used to model complex relationships between classes. It not suitable just to mark different things.

Comment: I roughly understand what you mean to just add new properties if there is a new type of object to store. I guess I don't really have much of a choice here.

Comment: @Stein121 why don't you have a choice?

Comment: I am constrained by time, either I research more into this to find the perfect 1 method handle all derived classes or I just work with what I have now. That one perfect method is probably near impossible to achieve too.

Comment: @Stein121 you can't have magic-method edit-everything in C++. The language is not dynamic enough for it.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you have methods for editing your derived items, like `void editSkates(Skates*)`, `void editSkateboard(Skateboard*)` etc.

Then you can apply [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). Create abstract `Visitor` class with `visit` method, overloaded for every distinct `Item` subclass:

```
class ItemVisitor{
public:
    virtual void visit(Skates*) = 0;
    virtual void visit(Skateboard*) = 0;
    //... one function for every subclass
};
```

Create `virtual void accept(ItemVisitor&) = 0;` method in your `Item` class. In every subclass, say, `Skates`, override this method to call the correct `visit`:

```
void Skates::accept(ItemVisitor& visitor){
    visitor.visit(this);
}
```

Now you can inherit `ItemVisitor` to do specific things with specific subclasses, like so:

```
class EditVisitor: public ItemVisitor{
public:
    virtual void visit(Skates* skates){
        skates->editSpecialSkatesProperty();
    }

    virtual void visit(Skateboard* skateboard){
        skateboard->editSpecialSkateboardProperty();
    }
};
```

And finally do this specific thing with your generic `Item * item` instance:

```
EditVisitor edit;
item->accept(edit);
```

Comment: Thanks for this visitor pattern, it seems like a nice way to separate my code structure. I will try implementing this, but this is not the answer I am looking for, which is to not have to write a new method every time I add a new derived class.